# How to make a Type-constructor part of the Functor typeclass if it has more than one Type-parameter?

Tags: haskell, functor, type-constructor

I am trying to understand the way the Functor-Typeclass works in Haskell. If you have a function `f :: a -> b -> c` and you want to partially apply it to the `argB` to get a function that takes one argument, you can simply do:

```
f' :: a -> c
f' x = f x argB
```

and use that. Is it possible to get such behavior when making something part of the Functor-Typeclass with something like this:

```
instance Functor (MyTypeconstructor _ argB) where
   fmap <implementation of fmap>
```

I know you can partially apply a Type-constructor to its first type-parameter (standart currying):

```
instance Functor (MyTypeconstructor argA) where
   fmap <implementation of fmap>
```

but how can you partially apply it to its `second / third / all except one` type-parameter, if this is possible?

thank you.

Comment: No, it is not possible, unfortunately. If it were, for `f::a->b`, is the type of `fmap f (undefined::F a a)` equal to `F a b` or `F b a`? The usual workaround is to define a custom `newtype` as jd823592 does below.

Comment: You can get the 'kind' of a data type by entering `:k datatype` in ghci. This is what you get for Maybe, `Maybe :: * -> *`. For a data type to be an instance of Functor, it has to be of kind `* -> *`.

MyTypeconstructor is of kind `* -> * -> *`. If you do want to create a functor, wrap it in a different type.

`ProxyTypeConstructor b a = MyTypeconstructor a b`

And then have a way to convert between these two data types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have `data F a b = ...`, define

```
newtype Fx a = Fx { unFx :: F a X }
```

to partially apply `F` to `X` in the second argument. Now you can use

```
instance Functor Fx where
    fmap f fa = ...
```

to define your instance for `F _ X`.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, you can write

```
newtype FlippedF a b = FlippedF { unFlip :: F b a }
```

and then

```
instance Functor (FlippedF argB)
```

Or even more generally,

```
newtype Flip f a b = Flip { unFlip :: f b a }

instance Functor (Flip F argB)
```

`Flip` and many more type-level combinators are defined in e.g. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.9.12/docs/Control-Compose.html#g:9 (and also http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.4.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor-Flip.html#t:Flip)